# Delete line based on column value in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to cut line(s) from a fixed length file and paste it into new file for the lines that start with 180 and position 35 has "N".
I am using ** bash **

```
**Sample input file:**
070000001                                                                                            075PRMAGDALENA F DEL                                                                                                  180AP997270518411                  Y02092014 
180AP997270518412                  N02092014 
180AP997270518413                  N03212013 
PAYMNT                                                                                               
190EM037490013798700                                                                                 
070000002                                                                                            075PRRERUCHA TROY A                                                                                                    195097130808020800                                                                                   070000003                                                                                            
180AP997270518423                  Y03212013 
**Sample input end**
```

**Code**:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do

## var=$((var+1))
  if [ ${line:0:3} = '180' ] && [ ${line:34:1} = 'N' ]  ;
  then
    echo $line > online_error.txt
  else
    echo $line > online_good.txt
  fi
done <"$file"
```

**Code end**

** The output start **

180AP997270518423 N03212013

** Output end **
In the above output the spaces are lost. I would want my output to have similar spacing as my input line. The letter "N" is positioned at 35 in my input file where as in out put its at 19.

The if part writes output to file however I've lost the formatting. I need to keep the original formatting as the output from this script is input for another mainframe program.

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean "I've lost the formatting"?

Comment: Use `echo "$line"` to preserve the spacing in the lines.

Comment: echo $line, somehow not preserving the spacing

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the statements "position 35 is N" and "the second field starts with N" are equivalent, you could use the `awk` command

```
awk '$1 ~ /^180/ && $2 ~ /^N/ {
       print $0 > "online_error.txt";
       next;
     }
     { print $0 > "online_good.txt" }' "$file"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the following alternative:

```
cat b.txt | grep -E '^180.{32}N'  > newFile.txt
```

To extract the lines that start with `180` and have `N` in column 35; and

```
cat b.txt | grep -E -v '^180.{32}N' > remainder.txt
```

for all the others.

Note - the `-E` flag is the one that is used on Mac OS for "extended regex". Alternatively you can use `egrep` - then you don't need the flag. I think this is the same in other versions of Unix.

If you are sure that the letter in the second column is always "the first letter after a space" you could also try

```
egrep '^180.* N' < b.txt > newFile.txt
```

and its complement:

```
egrep -v '^180.* N' < b.txt > newFile.txt
```

Comment: I used egrep and the remainder works fine but the newFile was produced with no records.

Comment: That is bizarre - because the `-v` flag says "everything that doesn't match", so you would expect the identical expression _without_ the `-v` flag to produce the rest… Is there any chance at all that you made a typo?